# PHP How to convert array with references into normal array and keep ref values?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

What is a simplest (fastest) way to convert array with references to normal array, but keep referenced values?

### E.g. convert something like:

```
Array &0 (
  0 => Array &2 (
    'req_id' => '395',
    'timestamp' => '1357349462',
    'website' => 'www.google.com'
  )
  1 => Array &3 (
    'req_id' => '397',
    'timestamp' => '1357349576',
    'website' => 'www.yahoo.com'
  )
)
```

---

### to something like this:

```
[
  [
    'req_id' => '395',
    'timestamp' => '1357349462',
    'website' => 'www.google.com'
  ],
  [
    'req_id' => '397',
    'timestamp' => '1357349576',
    'website' => 'www.yahoo.com'
  ]
];
```

---

I know, it can be done using iterator (foreach) but, is there shorter way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can use is `json_decode` combined with `json_encode`:

```
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($arr),true);
```